# Revisión continua de tiempo en Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite3, flask

Actualmente haciendo un borrador para una pequeña aplicación en *Flask*. ¿Cómo puedo mantener actualizada una sección de la página en tiempo real, en comparación con datos de una base de datos (SQLite3)?

Una sección de la página muestra datos de una tabla en un *Dropdown* de la siguiente forma:

En el archivo *Python*:

```
def getcitas():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    time = ("%s:%s" % (now.hour, now.minute))
    today = (datetime.date.today())
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute("SELECT * FROM Citas WHERE Fecha = ? AND Hora >= ?", (today, time,))
    Citas_Hoy = [dict(Hora=row[1], Paciente=row[2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return Citas_Hoy

@app.route('/')
def home():
    ## ... otra parte de código aquí  ...##
    Citas_Hoy = getcitas()
    return render_template("Index.html", Citas_Hoy=Citas_Hoy)
```

Que se pasa a la plantilla;

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><p>Hoy</p></li>
       {% for Citas in Citas_Hoy: %}
       <p>{{ Citas.Hora }}</p>
       <p>{{ Citas.Paciente }}</p>
       {% endfor %}
       <br>
```

Esto funciona bien, mostrando los datos correctos cuando se actualiza la página (manualmente, o navegando entre secciones).

¿Hay alguna forma de verificar la fecha y hora, para que estos datos, se actualicen en tiempo real (sin necesidad de actualizar manualmente la página)?

Googleando posibles respuestas he leido sobre *AJAX*, el protocolo *SSE* y *WebSockets*, pero no logro ver cómo cualquiera de ellas, se podría acoplar a la comparación con *SQLite3*.

Comment: Si, hay. Por ejemplo, AJAX, SSE o WebSocket. Y básicamente no les interesa con quién se acoplan, porque ese es problema de Flask, no de las páginas.

Comment: Yo he usado websockets en Flask. Pero te hace falta definir como la aplicación genera el evento cuando la base de datos se actualiza.

Comment: Una ves generado es evento, como comparar la hora actual con la de la base de datos? He leído sobre eventos pero estos son en función de input de usuario o tareas agendadas con cron por ejemplo. No he podido encontrar algo que aplique a continuamente comparar un dato de una base de datos con una variable (tiempo local por ejemplo) de forma continua.